# Criar Elementos HTML dinamicamente no Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Bom Dia!

Sou novo em Angular 2 e estou montando um projeto para aprimoramento pessoal um blog.

Essa tag "p"recebe o meu texto

```
<!-- Post Content -->
        <p id="post-aux">{{post.Texto}}</p>
```

Recebo o conteúdo do texto editado com tags HTML,porém recebo uma string desse texto como no exemplo abaixo:

```
    "<p>Olá Mundo</p>"
```

No Jquery usaria o append para criar esse elemento no meu HTML.
Existe algo que faça isso para mim no Angular 2?

Grato desde já

Comment: Não dá para usar Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<p [innerHTML]="post.Texto"></p>
```

Comment: Minutos atras vi um post falando sobre ele e acabei usando o mesmo,muito obrigado pela ajuda